# Find the occurrence of each character in a string?

Tags: python, string, character, frequency

I have been trying to solve this question lately but am unable to fetch the desired results.

I/p :- string = 'aabcccdeeffccddd'
Expected o/p :- a2bc3de2f2c2d3

my wrong solution:-

```
a = 'aabcccdeeffcc'
prev = ''
new = ''
count = 1
for x in a:    
    if len(new) == 0:
        new+=x
        prev = x
    elif x == prev:
        count+=1
        new+=str(count)
     
    elif x != new[-1]:
        new+=x
        prev = x
        count = 1
print(new)
```

please give your insights on how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this one line solution using `re.sub` along with a callback function:

```py
import re

inp = "aabcccdeeffccddd"
output = re.sub(r'(.)\1*', lambda m: m.group(1) + str(len(m.group())), inp)
print(output)  # a2b1c3d1e2f2c2d3
```